# extract specific element from nested elements using lxml html

Tags: python, html, parsing, xpath, lxml

Hi all I am having some problems that I think can be attributed to xpath problems. I am using the html module from the lxml package to try and get at some data. I am providing the most simplified situation below, but keep in mind the html I am working with is much uglier.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <table>
                    <tr><td><u><b>Header1</b></u></td></tr> 
                    <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td></tr>
        </table>
     </td></tr>
</table>
```

What I really want is the deeply nested table, because it has the header text "Header1".
I am trying like so:

```
from lxml import html
page = '...'
tree = html.fromstring(page)
print tree.xpath('//table[//*[contains(text(), "Header1")]]')
```

but that gives me all of the table elements. I just want the one table that contains this text. I understand what is going on but am having a hard time figuring out how to do this besides breaking out some nasty regex. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//td[text() = 'Header1']/ancestor::table[1]
```

Comment: @DerrickPetzold: For *good* XPath/XSLT resources see this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev The answer you referring to has been deleted: [internet archive snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20120530035704/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589)

Answer (score 2):

Find the header you are interested in and then pull out its table.

```
//u[b = 'Header1']/ancestor::table[1]
```

or

```
//td[not(.//table) and .//b = 'Header1']/ancestor::table[1]
```

Note that `//` *always* starts at the document root (!). You can't do:

```
//table[//*[contains(text(), "Header1")]]
```

and expect the inner predicate (`//*…`) to magically start at the right context. Use `.//` to start at the context node. Even then, this:

```
//table[.//*[contains(text(), "Header1")]]
```

won't work since even the outermost table contains the text `'Header1'` somewhere deep down, so the predicate evaluates to true for every table in your example. Use `not()` like I did to make sure no other tables are nested.

Also, don't test the condition on every node `.//*`, since it can't be true for every node to begin with. It's more efficient to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would work for you:

```
tree.xpath("//table[not(descendant::table)]/*[contains(., 'Header1')]")
```

The `not(descendant::table)` bit ensures that you're getting the innermost table.

Answer (score 0):

```
table, = tree.xpath('//*[.="Header1"]/ancestor::table[1]')
```

- `//*[text()="Header1"]` selects an element anywhere in a document with text `Header1`.
- `ancestor::table[1]` selects the first ancestor of the element that is `table`.

#### Complete example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from lxml import html

page = """
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <table>
                    <tr><td><u><b>Header1</b></u></td></tr> 
                    <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td></tr>
        </table>
     </td></tr>
</table>
"""

tree = html.fromstring(page)
table, = tree.xpath('//*[.="Header1"]/ancestor::table[1]')
print html.tostring(table)
```

Comment: While this is correct for the example, I think it is too generic to use `//*[.="Header1"]`. There could be a `see <i>Header1</i>` somewhere in the input and your expression would match the `<i>`.

Comment: @Tomalak: It always matches *`<table>`* element. It doesn't matter what element contains `"Header1"` as long as it is somewhere inside the `<table>` element.

Comment: Right, no argument there. Still, my point is that you might not be matching the *table header* as such, but anything generic that by chance contains the text `'Header1'`. So chances are you match the wrong table.